# How to change point size using geojson file in D3

Tags: d3.js

I need a little help. I think this is a primitive question but I am really stuck at this point. I have a map in orthographic projection in d3 and a geojson file that contains points representing earthquakes. I am able to display the points. They have the same size. But I want to change a size of each point refering to its "mag" number in geojson file. Can anybody help me please? 
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300" />
<style>
.graticule {
 fill: none;
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width:.5;
 opacity:.1;
}
.land {
 fill: rgb(117, 87, 57);
 stroke: black;
 stroke-opacity: .2;
}
</style>
<body>
<body background="space5.jpg"> 
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var diameter = 700,
    radius = diameter/2,
    velocity = .005,
    then = Date.now();

var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
        .scale(radius - 2)
        .translate([radius, radius])
        .clipAngle(90);

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", diameter)
.attr("height", diameter);

var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection)

var ocean_fill = svg.append("defs").append("radialGradient")
      .attr("id", "ocean_fill")
      .attr("cx", "75%")
      .attr("cy", "25%");
  ocean_fill.append("stop").attr("offset", "55%").attr("stop-color", "#ddf");
  ocean_fill.append("stop").attr("offset", "100%").attr("stop-color", "#9ab");

//Load sphere 
var globe = {type: "Sphere"};
svg.append("path")
.datum(globe)
.attr("d", path)
.style("fill", "url(#ocean_fill)");


//graticule
svg.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", path);


//Load countries
d3.json("world-110m.json", function(error, topology) {
var land = topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries),
globe = {type: "Sphere"};
svg.insert("path")
  .datum(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries))
  .attr("class", "land")
  .attr("d", path);
});


//Load earthquakes
d3.json("2.5_day.geojson", function(json) {
 svg.selectAll("path.day")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d",path)
    .style("fill", "red")        
});
//rotate everything
d3.timer(function() {
var angle = velocity * (Date.now() - then);
projection.rotate([angle,0,0]);
svg.selectAll("path")
.attr("d", path); 
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a part of geojson file (just one point):

```
{
type: "FeatureCollection",
metadata: {
    generated: 1396609484000,
    url: http://...,
    title: USGS magnitude,
    api: String,
    count: Integer,
    status: Integer
},

features: [
    {
        type: "Feature",
        properties: {
            mag: 5.2,
            place: 70km SW of Iquique, Chile,
            time: 1396605206040,
            updated: 1396606883841,
            tz: Integer,
            url: String,
            detail: String,
            felt:Integer,
            cdi: Decimal,
            mmi: Decimal,
            alert: String,
            status: String,
            tsunami: Integer,
            sig:Integer,
            net: String,
            code: String,
            ids: String,
            sources: String,
            types: String,
            nst: Integer,
            dmin: Decimal,
            rms: Decimal,
            gap: Decimal,
            magType: String,
            type: String
        },
        geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [
                longitude,
                latitude,
                depth
            ]
        },
        id: String

    },
    ...
]
}
```

Thank you for your time reading this and for your comments.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`.pointRadius()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#pointRadius) of `path` to do this:

```
var path = d3.geo.path()
             .projection(projection)
             .pointRadius(function(d) { return d.properties.mag; });
```

You may also want to have a scale to map the data to circle sizes, e.g.

```
var scale = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([minMag, maxMag]).range([2, 10]);
// ...
  .pointRadius(function(d) { return scale(d.properties.mag); });
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Lars. I was trying your code but it doesn't work somehow. Something silly is maybe missing to me here. It does not display anything when I put this code  .pointRadius(function(d) { return d.properties.mag; }); to